# How to get multiple goals in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following code:

```
move(state(on(X, NewX), OldY, Z), state(NewX, on(X, OldY), Z)).
move(state(on(X, NewX), Y, OldZ), state(NewX, Y, on(X, OldZ))).

move(state(OldX, on(Y, NewY), Z), state(on(Y, OldX), NewY, Z)).
move(state(X, on(Y, NewY), OldZ), state(X, NewY, on(Y, OldZ))).

move(state(OldX, Y, on(Z, NewZ)), state(on(Z, OldX), Y, NewZ)).
move(state(X, OldY, on(Z, NewZ)), state(X, on(Z, OldY), NewZ)).
```

The problem is that I want to know all the possibilities that I can use.

For example, if I type

```
move(state(on(a,void), void, void), A).
```

I get

```
A = state(void, on(a,void), void).
```

But also I want the next option:

```
state(void, void, on(a,void)).
```

Comment: Did you try `findall/3`?

Comment: Yes, i used this:

findall(state(void, on(a,void), void), move(state(void, on(a,void), void), A),Bag).

, but I get Bag = [state(void, on(a, void), void), state(void, on(a, void), void)].

Answer (score 0):

When Prolog gives you the first answer, press <kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon) or <kbd>Space</kbd> to get the next answer (SWI-Prolog tells me that it also accepts <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, or <kbd>Tab</kbd> for this). Press <kbd>.</kbd> (period) or <kbd>Enter</kbd> if you don't want any more answers.

Comment: Thanks, I get the options that I want, but how can I get a list with all the possible answers?

Comment: Please edit the question. Put in the question *exactly* what you want the results to look like. Apparently you want a list of all answers, but the `findall/3` solution which gives you the list of all answers wasn't what you wanted either. We cannot help if it's not clear what you are asking.